# auto closing custom helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I am trying to implement auto closing custom helper.
I have found how to to this below:
[Custom html helpers: Create helper with "using" statement support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676746/custom-html-helpers-create-helper-with-using-statement-support)


I have done everything except:
what i am supossed to return here?

```
public static Action BeginField(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formName)
{
  string result = string.Format("<div class=\"FullWidthForm\"><span>{0}</span>", formName);
  result += "<ul class=\"Left\">";
  htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(result);
  return ???????
}
```

I am asking because i have error as follows:

> Error 9   'FieldContainer.BeginField(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string)': not all code paths return a
>   value

so i do not have idea what to return

---

Ok I have created everything how ever:

```
public static class DisposableExtensions
    {
        public static IDisposable DisposableField(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formName)
        {
            //'HtmlHelpers.DisposableHelper' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments
            return new DisposableHelper(
                () => htmlHelper.BeginField(formName),
                () => htmlHelper.EndField());
        }

        public static void BeginField(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formName)
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("<ul><li>" + formName + "</li>");

        }
        public static void EndField(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("</ul>");
        }

    }

    class DisposableHelper : IDisposable
    {
        private Action end;
        // When the object is create, write "begin" function
        // make this public so it can be accessible
       public DisposableHelper(Action begin, Action end)
        {
            this.end = end;
            begin();
        }
        // When the object is disposed (end of using block), write "end" function
        public void Dispose()
        {
            end();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `BeginField` does not need to return `Action`.

[Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) is a delegate, a callback you need to pass to the `DisposableHelper` constructor. You will setup it as `() -> htmlHelper.BeginField(formName)`. DisposableHelper works by remembering the two callbacks you pass in - first to start the tag (`BeginField`) which is called immediately, second to end the tag (`EndField`) which is called on disposal of the `DisposableHelper`.

**UPDATE**: This is how you should implement it.

a) Copy the `DisposableHelper` class.

b) Write an extension to `DisposableExtensions`:

```
public static class DisposableExtensions
{
    public static IDisposable DisposableField(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formName)
    {
        return new DisposableHelper(
            () => htmlHelper.BeginField(formName),
            () => htmlHelper.EndField()
        );
    }
}
```

c) Change your `BeginField` declaration to return `void`:

```
public static void BeginField(...)
```

d) Add `EndField` method to close the tag.

e) Use it this way:

```
using (Html.DisposableField("MyForm"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 I think the answer here could equally be 'read the other answer properly'... or perhaps I am just feeling grumpy today...

Comment: Yep i did read that but there is how to write it into the return,Maybe my head just does not get it