# Use a disposable helper .net mvc backend

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I have an IDisposable  HTML helper to create a specific html structure that I need very often in my app. I use it with razor and its works perfectly

```
    @using (Html.SlidePanel("settings-button"))
    {
         <span>panel content</span>
    }
```

I have a html helper component based on the structure and I want to use my SlidePanel inside.

```
public class MyComponent : IHtmlString
{
    private readonly HtmlHelper html;

    public MyComponent(HtmlHelper html)
    {
        this.html = html;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Render();
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return ToString();
    }

    private string Render()
    {
        // I want to use my SlidePanel at this place

        string renderHtml = "<div>component html</div>";
        return renderHtml;
    }
}

public static class MyComponentHtmlHelper
{
    public static MyComponent MyComponent(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return new MyComponent(html);
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: If i understand you correctly, try to look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/676845/2115584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution thanks to Baximilian and StriplingWarrior answers

- Yes, I need to intercept the string that SlidePanel would normally be sending to the general output. So I can't use the ViewContext.Writer.
- And yes, I need to send methods a parameters to my SlidePanel constructor.

So the solution is to add a second constructor to SlidePanel class :

```
    public string HtmlString;

    public SlidePanel(Func<string> begin, Func<string> content, Func<string> end)
    {
        this.HtmlString = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", begin(), content(), end());
    }
```

And add public helpers inside the SlidePanel Component class

```
    public static string BeginSlidePanel(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return BeginHtml();
    }

    public static string ContentSlidePanel(this HtmlHelper html, string htmlString)
    {
        return htmlString;
    }

    public static string EndSlidePanel(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return EndHtml();
    }
```

And then, I can use my SlidePanel like this :

```
    new SlidePanel(
    () => html.BeginSlidePanel(), 
    () => html.ContentSlidePanel(GetMyHtmlContent()), 
    () => html.EndSlidePanel()).HtmlString
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to intercept the string that SlidePanel would normally be sending to the general output. Something like this should work:

```
var originalWriter = html.ViewContext.Writer;
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    html.ViewContext.Writer = stringWriter;
    using (html.SlidePanel())
    {
        stringWriter.Write("<div>component html</div>");
    }
    html.ViewContext.Writer = originalWriter;
    return stringWriter.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here you go, example [HERE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yf9Vib)

```
public static class DisposableExtensions
{
  public static IDisposable DisposableDiv(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
   {
     return new DisposableHelper(
        () => htmlHelper.BeginDiv(),
        () => htmlHelper.EndDiv());
   }

  public static void BeginDiv(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
   {
     htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("<div>");
   }


  public static void EndDiv(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
   {
     htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write("</div>");
   }
  }
}
```

As you can see in example "Hello Stranger" placed in additional div